Does QED explain why Moving charge produce magnetic field?
I wonder that moving charge produce magnetic fields. Now a days quantum field theory explain much of particle physics their underlying mediate particles.
But can QED explain why moving charge produce magnetic field? Is there any theoretical approach to try to explain this?

It is the exact same reason as the classical Maxwell's equations. What are you trying to discuss about?

It is an observational fact that moving charges have velocity-dependent forces. And you cannot construct a relativistic theory using only charges and electric fields. QFT has nothing to do with it.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

It's actually the other way round. Maxwell's equations explain why a moving charge produces a magnetic field, and we get quantum electrodynamics by quantising Maxwell's equations.
The link between moving charges and electric fields comes from special relativity i.e. the fact that spacetime is four dimensional. Maxwell didn't realise it at the time but his equations are consistent with special relativity (technically we say they are Lorentz covariant) and indeed this was one of the clues that guided Einstein towards the discovery of relativity. One of the objects we get from Maxwell's equations is the electromagnetic four potential, and quantising this is what leads us to quantum electrodynamics.
There already lots and lots of questions about how moving charges are linked to magnetic fields. My preferred way of looking at it is that with only the electric field or only the magnetic field we cannot create fields that are consistent with special relativity. We have to combine electric and magnetic fields into an object called the electromagnetic tensor. Then what we call electric and magnetic fields are just three dimensional views of this four dimensional electromagnetic field.

Thanks for your answer. I wonder that ferady tensor explain how both fields unify.They are not seperate quantity.Am I right please correct if I wrong?

Correct. The electric and magnetic fields are not separate objects. They are just parts of the electromagnetic tensor.

Thanks John for your reply

@SanketThakkar I'd guess you won't be learning special relativity for a few years yet, but if and when you do learn it you'll be amazed at how elegantly it explains things that seem mysterious when they are taught at school.

Yaa I am following Electrodynamics by Griffiths so I try to understand special relativity in Electrodynamics so I need more to learn about it
